# Can I get the element by Tag from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I want to get back a button, I've already assign the tag to there, how can I do so?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use the `viewWithTag` method. e.g. if your button is in your controller's view and your button's tag is 100 the following line will return the button:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
```

**EDIT:**

Get view with particular tag in Swift -

```
let view = self.view.viewWithTag(100)
```

If you want to make sure you have the specific type of view, say a UIButton, you should check the type:

```
if let button = self.view.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
```

//Now you can get your button based on tag value

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get View using tag
        UITextField *textFieldInView = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag+1000];
        UILabel *labelInView = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag+2000];

//Print its content based on the tags
        NSLog(@"The tag is %d ", textFieldInView.tag);
        NSLog(@"The tag is %d ", labelInView.tag);
        NSLog(@"The Content is %@ ", textFieldInView.text);
        NSLog(@"The Content is  %@ ", labelInView.text);
```